# Issues converting docker run command to a docker-compose.yml config

Tags: docker, port-forwarding, isc-dhcpd, docker-compose

I am trying to set up `dhcpd` in a docker image for my home network.

I have cloned [this repository](https://github.com/networkboot/docker-dhcpd), and had it working fine with my `dhcpd.conf`

To run it, I have to execute this command using `docker run`:

```
docker run -it \
  --rm --init \
  --net host \
  -v "$(pwd)/data":/data \
  networkboot/dhcpd eth0
```

Which works beautifully.

But I want to bundle this with my DNS docker, so I tried to convert it to a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
#
# Imagine the DNS stuff here
#
  dhcp:
    build:
      context: ./dhcp
      network: host
      args:
        - eth0
    container_name: dhcpd
    volumes:
      - ./dhcp/data:/data
```

This does NOT go too well:

> You must add the 'docker run' option '--net=host' if you want to provide DHCP service to the host network.

> dhcpd   | No subnet declaration for eth0 (172.19.0.2).
> dhcpd   | ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
> dhcpd   |    you want, please write a subnet declaration
> dhcpd   |    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
> dhcpd   |    to which interface eth0 is attached. **

I'm guessing that I have done something wrong with the `network: host part` but I am new to docker, so I'm at a loss as to where I have gone wrong.

```
$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.21.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.7.3
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was apparently to add `network_mode: host` to the file

so now it is:

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
  dhcp:
    build:
      context: ./dhcp
      network: host
      args:
        - eth0
    container_name: dhcpd
    volumes:
      - ./dhcp/data:/data
    network_mode: host
```